# Bitbucket iOS pipeline yml file setup

Tags: ios, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Looked through the documentation on the Atlassian website but have had no luck. Is there a way to set up a build pipeline yml file in Bitbucket for iOS projects?

I have tried just adding the script into the pipeline but that seems to fail every time:

```
pipelines:
default:
- step:
    script:
      - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace <project-workspace> -scheme <project-name> -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=<iOS version>' build | xcpretty
```

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, pipelines only execute builds on specified Docker containers as Jim mentioned, and currently no docker container is capable of building for iOS (at least legally afaik).

Answer (score 0):

Which image are you using? Pipelines uses Docker containers to provide the appropriate environment for your tests or builds, so you should be able either to use an image from hub.docker.com that contains what you need, or to build one of your own.